# How can I export only a specific page in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, vercel

I want a build and export specific page in NextJS, how can I do it?

i.e. as a result I want to get only a specific HTML page in the "out" directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

> For more advanced scenarios, you can define a parameter called exportPathMap in your next.config.js file to configure exactly which pages will be generated.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap